# Room+dagger 2. NPE

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-room

Using Room+LiveData+Dagger2+Kotlin

db code:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(MonthlyBudget::class, Purchase::class), version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(DateTypeConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun budgetDAO(): BudgetDAO
    abstract fun purchaseDAO(): PurchaseDAO
}
```

Method in dagger2 which provides db

```
@Provides
fun providesAppDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "my-budget-db").allowMainThreadQueries().build()
```

Method in dagger 2 which return null

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("CurrentMonthBudget")
fun provideCurrentMonthBudget(repository: AppRepository): MonthlyBudget = repository.currentMonthBudget()
```

Object's inject

```
@Inject
@Nullable
@field:Named("CurrentMonthBudget")
lateinit var currentMonthBudget: MonthlyBudget
```

Because of the null data i getting this

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method
```

This is how i did it: created a nullcheck and If 'If' gets back 'true',  I add default values in db.

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(MonthlyBudget::class, Purchase::class), version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(DateTypeConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun budgetDAO(): BudgetDAO
    abstract fun purchaseDAO(): PurchaseDAO
    companion object {
        fun getInstance(context:Context):AppDatabase {
            val database = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "my-budget-db").allowMainThreadQueries().build()
            if (database.budgetDAO().queryCurrentMonthBudget() == null) {
                database.budgetDAO().insert(MonthlyBudget(0), MonthlyBudget(0))
                database.purchaseDAO().insert(Purchase("default",0))
            }
            return database
        }
    }
}
```

What should i do? Fill the db? If so, tell me the better way to do it, or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set the `@Nullable` on the `provideCurrentMonthBudget`. Also since this is kotlin, the return type should be `MonthlyBudget?` - kotlin denotes nullable types with a `?`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I had to use nullable types in DAO and in Provider's method (it has to  have Nullable) and add only  Nullable annotation in Inject because lateinit var cant be nullable.Thank you